# How to include 2 parents to a child list in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have this class and a context class:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int ForeignId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Parent Parent{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ForeignId")]
    public virtual Foreign Foreign{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GrandChild> GrandChildren { get; set; }
}

public class GrandChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ChildId")]
    public virtual Child Child{ get; set; }
}

public class Foreign
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I want to show a list of Parent with Including their children and granchildren. I want to include Foreign table, too. because I need its fields.
I wrote this code:

```
var list = context.Parents.Include(p => p.Children).ThenInclude(p => p.GrandChildren).Tolist();
```

**How Can I add or include foreign table to this query?**

I wrote below code but it had error:

```
var list = context.Parents
    .Include(p => p.Children)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.GrandChildren)
    .Include(p => p.Children.FirstOrDefault().Foreign).Tolist();
```

Comment: See the duplicate, in this case, add `.Include(p => p.Children).ThenInclude(c => c.Foreign)` instead of the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 2 includes:

```
 var list = context.Parents

                .Include(p => p.Children)
                .ThenInclude(c => c.GrandChildren)
                .Include(p => p.Children)
                .ThenInclude(c => c.Foreign).ToList();
```